# What is the equation for the layer weight node?

Tags: shaders

The layer weight node has two outputs: Fresnel and Facing.

Does anyone know the equations to both outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one, or to be more precise, there are several, and some of them are GPU kernels that depend on the GPU's implementation of Fresnel.

Here's the code for the C version, embedded in a header file so it can be inlined: [`svm_node_layer_weight`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/intern/cycles/kernel/svm/svm_fresnel.h#L40).  It makes a call to [`fresnel_dielectric_cos`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/intern/cycles/kernel/closure/bsdf_util.h#L104) to calculate the Fresnel value. It calculates layer weight inline.

Comment: Ok kind of overwhelmed by the code. Anways thanks I'm just going to accept the answer as is.